# How to access class variables in the constructor? (node.js OOP)

Tags: javascript, oop, node.js

Is there some way to access a class variable in the constructor?

```
var Parent = function() {
  console.log(Parent.name);
};
Parent.name = 'parent';

var Child = function() {
  Parent.apply(this, arguments);
}
require('util').inherits(Child, Parent);
Child.name = 'child';
```

i.e Parent's constructor should log "parent" and child's Constructor should log "child" based one some class variable in each class.

The above code doesn't work as I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is in vanilla js:

```
var Parent = function() {
  console.log(this.name);
};
Parent.prototype.name = 'parent';

var Child = function() {
  Parent.apply(this, arguments);
}

Child.prototype = new Parent();
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
Child.prototype.name = 'child';

var parent = new Parent();
var child = new Child();
```

utils.inherits just simplifies the

```
Child.prototype = new Parent();
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
```

into

```
util.inherits(Child, Parent);
```

Comment: utils.inherits does more than described (no instance of a subclass).